# Android app crashes with Drawable resource as background

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable

This is my first android project so please bear with me. My app is crashing whenever i change a layout's background, I noticed that the layout won't crash if the background drawable does not include a `(v21)` next to it. For example setting the background as `@drawable/gradient_bg` it works fine, on the other hand, `@drawable/gradient_bg_purple` it crashes the application when the layout is loaded.

[image]

What does the `(v21)` mean ? I'm guessing it has to do with an android API v? Does that mean I should have a different file for all versions ? :/

I'm testing on an HTC - Android V-4.1.2 - HTC SDk level - 5.26

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`v21` means that the resource will be used/available on Android versions 21 and up. So in your case, that resource will be non existent for any Android versions lower than that.

**Update**
You should take those drawables out of `drawable-v21` and place them in the appropriate folder based on your desired density. For example, place it in `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

**v21** represents the minimum API level that will use this drawable.
You are running Android 4.1.2, which uses API **v16**.

Apparently, you created a `drawable-v21` directory in your resources (`res`) directory.
Please check if that's the case and move the drawable to the `drawable` directory.

If that is indeed that case, it may be because Android Studio suggested this change and you're using features that are specific to v21 API.
We can provide more help if you show us this `gradient_bg_purple.xml` file.